# Sci fi short story about a boy experiencing space travel out of suspended animation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, suspended-animation

I'm looking for the name of a short story about family on space flight.

The boy somehow stayed out of suspended animation, possibly out of curiosity.

At the end, with "empty eyes" he answers what it was like.

Comment: "Longer than you think, Dad!" it cackled.

Answer (score 16):

This may be '[The Jaunt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jaunt)' by Stephen King, first published in 1981 then later in the compendium *Skeleton Crew*. It is a teleportation process, not starflight, and the passengers are simply put under mild anesthesia to render them unconscious for the transfer. The boy is permanently traumatized (in graphic King fashion) due to the fact that perception of time is nearly infinitely magnified while the brain is being transported.

Comment: Huh.. Is a p-book (your profile) a book recorded in ink on dead tree?  I think if you're going 'retro' you might as well demand books chiseled into stone!  ;)

Comment: That's it!!! Thk u  metamaterial girl.

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65088/155831) the answer when the site allows.

Comment: I was into p-books before they were retro!

Comment: As was I.  Wouldn't consider getting another one now though, I respect trees (and breathing oxygen) too much.  :)

Comment: Fortunately my own collection is largely grandfathered (literally in some cases). And I keep books longer than I've kept any wooden furniture I own. ;)